# What SQL command to use to select and export multiple column names without any data be returned from the command

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table RV_Test and a column RV_Test.ColumnX and I need to export just the name of the column — in this case ColumnX — but do not want any data returned. How do I do this with a simple command?

Comment: Using what DBMS?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something different?

Comment: I always use `SELECT * WHERE 1=0`.

Comment: One I've used for SQL Server is `SELECT TOP 0 ...`.  That may work with `LIMIT` in MySQL as well, but I've never tried.

Comment: What you mean by saying: "*do not want any data returned*"? If there is no data, a null value is returned.

Comment: `SELECT rv_test.columnX FROM rv_test WHERE 1=0` in this case..  I've only seen 1 approach 0, never equal (even on exceptionally small values of 1 and large values of 0) so this will always return no records, but it will return the table layout.

Comment: SELECT  * from table LIMIT 0; 
This works in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL answer (since no dbms specified):

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'RV_Test'
  and column_name = 'ColumnX'
```

will give you lots of info about the column.

The column `DATA_TYPE` gives you the data type, `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`, `NUMERIC_SCALE`, `NUMERIC_PRECISION`, `DATETIME_PRECISION` etc gives you data type specific info.